# Radio Button Label styling

Tags: css, radio-button, label

I have some Radio Buttons as shown here:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="Duration" value="Duration"/>
<label"Duration">Date Range</label>
```

I have tried several ways, but i am unable to change the styling for the label of these radio Buttons

Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to correct the label code, you have `<label"Duration">` and it should have "for", like this:

```
<label for="Duration">
```

(read here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Then you need to target the `<label>` with your CSS.

Try this in your CSS definitions:

```
label {
   text-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To contribute a little to jackJoe
a little something on the side:

"i would recommend using class over 'id' because class is used for muliply uses for the same purpose, like a bunch of radiobuttons that need the same style, id however is for most of the time one time only styles.";

```
<label class="duration">
```

in css you need the '.' to call it a class and a '#' to call it an id (sorry for my bad english)

css:

```
.duration{
width:21px;
height:21px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image:url(images/radiobutton.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

on the side watch out for using Capslock letters in the beginning its better to use only small letters.

Comment: The class attribute '<label class="duration">' will help with styling, but what the author with the proven answer wanted to say was: When you use '<label for="duration">' then the label will be pointing to the corresponding input element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample styling

```
.radio {
  width: 19px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  background: url(checkbox.gif) no-repeat;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: The OP would like to style the label and not the radio alone :)